# what is wrong with this loop? continue isn't working here

Tags: python

```
blueberries=0
raspberries=0
while raspberries>-1:
    print('Enter a number for blueberries:')
    raspberries=float(input('Enter a number'))
    print('Enter a nuumber for raspberries:')
    blueberries=float(input('Enter a number'))
    if raspberries==0:
        continue
    print(blueberries+raspberries)
```

the continue isn't working in here I have tried multiple times

Comment: Please paste the code as text and not as an image.

Comment: Understood will do

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed-up your `blueberries` and `raspberries` variables:

```
print("Enter a number for blueberries:")
raspberries=float(input("Enter number"))  # should have stored in blueberries
print("Enter # raspberries:")
blueberries=float(input("Enter number"))  # should have stored in raspberries
```

That is why when you entered 47, it got stored in `raspberries`.
So `if raspberries==0` will be False.

You just need to store in the correct variables:

```
>>> blueberries=0
>>> raspberries=0
>>> while raspberries>-1:
...   print("Enter a number for blueberries:")
...   blueberries=float(input("Enter number "))
...   print("Enter a number for raspberries:")
...   raspberries=float(input("Enter number "))
...   if raspberries==0:
...     continue
...   print(blueberries+raspberries)
... 
Enter a number for blueberries:
Enter number 40
Enter a number for raspberries:
Enter number 5
45.0
Enter a number for blueberries:
Enter number 47
Enter a number for raspberries:
Enter number 0          
Enter a number for blueberries:   # continued here, did not print
Enter number
```

You could actually simplify your multiple `print`'s:

```
blueberries=0
raspberries=0
while raspberries>-1:
    blueberries=float(input("Enter number of blueberries: "))
    raspberries=float(input("Enter number of raspberries: "))
    if raspberries==0:
        continue
    print(blueberries + raspberries)
```

Lastly, instead of `continue`, what you might be looking for is a `break`, which will exit the loop if `raspberries==0`.

```
blueberries=0
raspberries=0
while raspberries>-1:
    blueberries=float(input("Enter number of blueberries: "))
    raspberries=float(input("Enter number of raspberries: "))
    if raspberries==0:
        break
    print(blueberries + raspberries)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ☺️ its fixed cause of you, sorry because of the first post didnt read the rules wont happen again  thanks again